# Why does GooglePlay in app purchase return error PG-GEMF-02?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I am developing an android app using unity 2020.1.7 (Unity IAP 2.1.0)

I uploaded my build to google play console, and started closed testing
Everything was fine, I was able to make test purchases, but recently on all my devices I get the error "An error occurred. Please try again. PG-GEMF-02."

In IAP logs I can see the following:

```
Purchase canceled - Response: 6:Error
onIabPurchaseFinished: false
6:Error (response: 6:Error)
```

Please advise me:

1. What does the PG-GEMF-02 error mean?
2. How can I fix it?

Thanks

PS: I've already tried basic advice like "delete googleplay store cache " / "reboot device" / "delete and re-add account to testers" / etc, - no luck

PPS: [Please see attached filtered log](https://justpaste.it/2f20s)

Answer (score 1):

try to check if your test is still active (in the GP console Testing > Closed Testing > ) and renew test activity if necessary.

If your test is inactive, you cant perform test purchases

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. When I came back it worked!

I was using flutter, but I found that when doing "license testing", I think my old subscription must have expired when I tried to upgrade.  I wish I could help more, but maybe that could be the problem? License testing subscriptions renew every 5 minutes and only go for like 30 minutes total, so I don't know what to say except that could be the problem (it expired before changing plans).  Hope that helps somebody.